# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'product')

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a private variable called product which I initialize in the constructor. Then I have an array.forEach() in the ngOnInit. console.log shows the value I'm trying to store in product but I'm getting a 'Cannot Read Properties' of undefined on product. What am I doing wrong?

```
private product: string;

constructor(private service: Service) {
  this.product = "";
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.service.sections.forEach(function (value) {

  if (this.product) {
    this.product = value.Product.ShortName;
  } else {
    this.product = "";
  }
  console.log(value.Product.ShortName);
});
}
```

Comment: Replace function (value) with (value: any) =>

Answer (score 1):

@MikeOne, place an important mark.

Your problem occurs due a context error, so
the member class `product` should be not referred with `this`

because into a traditional js function it looks to function context itself.

So assigning it to an global accessor whereas can be accessible should fix.

```
   ngOnInit() {
      var self = this
      this.service.sections.forEach(function (value) {

      if (self.product) {
         self.product = value?.Product?.ShortName || "";
      } else {
         self.product = "";
      }
      console.log(value.Product.ShortName);
   });
 }
```

But as legacy, here a tip of how proceed if some received value into callback can be null.

So javascript throw an exception when you're trying read a property of that null, such `Product`

you can use a handful elvis operator `?` to avoid exceptions like that.

so your assignment should be written in this style:

```
this.product = value?.Product?.ShortName || null;
```

Comment: His callback is not an arrow function, so product does not exist on ‘this’..

Comment: Yeah! agreed with you

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `function (value) {...}` to an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to this, arguments or super, and should not be used as methods.

```js
this.service.sections.forEach((section) => { 
  if (this.product) {
    this.product = section.Product.ShortName;
  } else {
    this.product = "";
  }
  console.log(section.Product.ShortName);
});
```